# Connect a raspberry Pi to a Apple 30 pin dock (or car)

Tags: audio, connection, connectors, cars

Anyone know if it would be possible using an apple 30 pin connector - which normally supplies power and receive an audio/data connection for music from a raspberry pi?

So Ideally the raspberry pi:

- would receive power from dock via the connector
- Output audio to the dock/car
- Receive control command from the dock/car (next track, previous track, possible navigation to playlists

I couldn't find anything that had done this.  I assume most applications like this have migrated to bluetooth for audio output.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds completely feasible as the iPod/iPhone is powered with 5V/1A.
I suggest you start with something like the [Dock Connector Pinout](http://pinouts.ru/PortableDevices/ipod_pinout.shtml).
But I think the most problematic part will be to get the Dock Connector Socket.